# Convert Excel macro to vbs script

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

Hello i have an qestion.

I have a csv file that has allot of data in it that I don’t want.
So I want to delete it. Im new to vbs scripting, so need some help.

How do I write this in vbs script?

```vb
Sub Work1()
'
' Work1 Makro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("B:D").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("F:F").Select
    Columns("F:AP").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1:E7").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("N23").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-21
    ChDir "C:\CSV"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\CSV\export.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
        CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I have got this far. It’s the part delete the columns that’s my problem.

```vb
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True  'set to False for production 

Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\csv\prov.csv")
Set objWorkbook = wb


‘replace values

Const FromValue = ","
Const ToValue = "."

Dim objExcel
Dim objWorksheet : Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'Dim objRange : Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange

objWorksheet.Cells.Replace FromValue, ToValue

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 


wb.SaveAs "C:\csv\data.csv"
wb.Close SaveChanges=True
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you want to do? What is it doing?

Comment: [Things to observe](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) when translating VBA to VBScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `Select` and the following `Selection` statements into one. For example, instead of:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete
```

You can do this:

```
objWorksheet.Columns("E:E").Delete
' or
objWorksheet.Columns("E").Delete
' or
objWorksheet.Columns(5).Delete
```

That will delete column E from the worksheet referenced by `objWorksheet`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thnak yuou for the quick answer.
It work great this is the final script.

```html
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True  'set to False for production 
 
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\csv\prov.csv")
set objWorksheet = xl
Set objExcel = xl

objWorksheet.Columns("A:A").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("B:D").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("C:H").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("E:E").Delete
objWorksheet.Columns("F:AP").Delete
objWorksheet.Rows("1:7").Delete

Const FromValue1 = ","
Const ToValue1 = "."


Dim objExcel
Dim objWorksheet : Set objWorksheet = xl
'Dim objRange : Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange
 
objWorksheet.Cells.Replace FromValue1, ToValue1

 
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 

wb.SaveAs "C:\csv\export.csv"
wb.Close SaveChanges=True

xl.Quit
```